# Android Cursor returning null

Tags: android, database, sqlite, textview, android-cursor

I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

I'm going to be utilizing Sqlite3 in my app and I've never used it before, so I wanted to make a separate project to test it out just to make sure I get it down.

I've run into this bug where I insert a few text values into a single column table, which seems to go fine. The problem occurs after I query all the names from the table and move through the cursor to get the info.

The way I'm testing this is by having a few TextViews and a Button. When the button is pressed, a TextView will have its text set to a value in the first position of the cursor, then `moveToNext()` will be called and the next TextView will update, etc.

The first TextView always updates correctly, however as soon as I try to set the next one after the first call of `moveToNext()`, I get a null exception.

Is there a way to see the contents of the Cursor in the debugger? I can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas? Here's the code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest.DBContract.DBInfo;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button testButton;
private TextView text1, text2, text3, text4;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    DBHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);

    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "getWritable successful");

    ContentValues sessionValues1 = new ContentValues();
    sessionValues1.put(DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME, "Sleep");

    ContentValues sessionValues2 = new ContentValues();
    sessionValues2.put(DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME, "Work");

    ContentValues sessionValues3 = new ContentValues();
    sessionValues3.put(DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME, "Reading");

    ContentValues sessionValues4 = new ContentValues();
    sessionValues4.put(DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME, "Walking");


    long newRowId1, newRowId2, newRowId3, newRowId4;
    //newRowId1 = db.insert(DBInfo.TABLE_SESSIONS, null, sessionValues1);
    //newRowId2 = db.insert(DBInfo.TABLE_SESSIONS, null, sessionValues2);
    //newRowId3 = db.insert(DBInfo.TABLE_SESSIONS, null, sessionValues3);
    //newRowId4 = db.insert(DBInfo.TABLE_SESSIONS, null, sessionValues4);

    String[] columns = {DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME};

    //DBHelper.deleteDB(db);

    final Cursor c = db.query(
            DBInfo.TABLE_SESSIONS,
            columns,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );


    testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            text1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME)));
            c.moveToNext();
            text2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME)));
            c.moveToNext();
            text3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME)));
            c.moveToNext();
            text4.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME)));
        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    db.close();
}


}
```

DataBaseHelper.java

```
package com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest.DBContract.DBInfo;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SoundScope.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DBInfo.TABLE_SESSIONS   +     " ("                           +
                DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME        +     " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);" +

        "CREATE TABLE " + DBInfo.TABLE_SOUND_INFO +     " ("                           +
                DBInfo._ID                        +     " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "       +
                DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION_NAME        +     " TEXT NOT NULL, "             +
                DBInfo.COLUMN_SOUND               +     " TEXT NOT NULL, "             +
                DBInfo.COLUMN_VOLUME              +     " REAL NOT NULL); "            +

        "CREATE TABLE " + DBInfo.TABLE_SOUNDS     +     " ("                           +
                DBInfo.COLUMN_SOUND_NAME          +     " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
                DBInfo.COLUMN_RAW                 +     " INTEGER NOT NULL, "          +
                DBInfo.COLUMN_DRAWABLE            +     " INTEGER NOT NULL);"          ;



private static final String SQL_DELETE_TABLES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBInfo.TABLE_SOUNDS     + ";"  +
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBInfo.TABLE_SOUND_INFO + ";"  +
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBInfo.TABLE_SESSIONS   + ";"  ;



private static DatabaseHelper mInstance;

public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        Log.d("DatabaseHelper","DatabaseHelper instance successful");
    }
    return mInstance;
}

//private to ensure singleton
private DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLES);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void deleteDB(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.delete(DBInfo.TABLE_SESSIONS,null,null);
    //db.delete(DBInfo.TABLE_SOUND_INFO,null,null);
    //db.delete(DBInfo.TABLE_SOUNDS,null,null);
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_TABLES);
}


}
```

DBContract.java

```
package com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest;


import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class DBContract {

public DBContract(){}

public static abstract class DBInfo implements BaseColumns{

    /*
    *
    * database schema
    *
    * */

    //sessions table
    public static final String TABLE_SESSIONS = "sessions";
    public static final String COLUMN_SESSION_NAME = "name";


    //sound_info
    //uses BaseColumns _ID
    public static final String TABLE_SOUND_INFO = "sound_info";
    public static final String COLUMN_SESSION = "session";
    public static final String COLUMN_SOUND = "sound";
    public static final String COLUMN_VOLUME = "volume";


    //soundS
    public static final String TABLE_SOUNDS = "sounds";
    public static final String COLUMN_SOUND_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_RAW = "raw";
    public static final String COLUMN_DRAWABLE = "drawable";

}

}
```

And the stack trace for the error:

```
01-21 11:17:12.319 9149-9149/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
01-21 11:17:12.319 9149-9149/? E/Zygote: v2
01-21 11:17:12.319 9149-9149/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10075
01-21 11:17:12.319 9149-9149/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
01-21 11:17:12.319 9149-9149/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram,    SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SAMSUNG-SM-N910A_5.1.1 ver=38
01-21 11:17:12.319 9149-9149/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SAMSUNG-SM-N910A_5.1.1_0038
01-21 11:17:12.319 9149-9149/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
01-21 11:17:12.319 9149-9149/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
01-21 11:17:12.319 9149-9149/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-21 11:17:12.359 9149-9149/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
01-21 11:17:12.359 9149-9149/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
01-21 11:17:12.449 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
01-21 11:17:12.489 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
01-21 11:17:12.489 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
01-21 11:17:12.549 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/DatabaseHelper: DatabaseHelper instance successful
01-21 11:17:12.559 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/MainActivity: getWritable successful
01-21 11:17:12.569 9149-9196/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-21 11:17:12.579 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
01-21 11:17:12.579 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
01-21 11:17:12.599 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
01-21 11:17:12.609 9149-9196/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest I/Adreno: EGLInit: QTI Build: 07/16/15, 126f54a, If3804f16ae
01-21 11:17:12.619 9149-9196/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-21 11:17:12.629 9149-9196/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 16384
01-21 11:17:12.629 9149-9196/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-21 11:17:12.699 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1f878246 time:177267508
01-21 11:17:15.329 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
01-21 11:17:15.429 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-21 11:17:15.429 9149-9149/com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest, PID: 9149
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.firsttread.anthony.databasetest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5242)
                                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10530)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21185)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your CREATE_TABLES and DELETE_TABLES are wrong. You cannot execute multiple SQL commands by separating them by a semicolon. You must execute a SQL command at a time.

Comment: I think moveToNext returns a boolean you can check. Also DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString() helps a lot

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi That wasn't the problem. The multi SQL commands seems to be working fine. The problem was that I had all of the TextViews as text1 when finding by id. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get NPE because of a problem with `findViewById()`

```
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
```

You're assigning to `text1` only, and then try to `setText` on the others (`text2`, `text3`, `text4`), which are nulls.

Comment: WOW! Thank you. Very embarrassing.